# Fast algorithm for partial text search

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm

I have a list of words describing actions, for example:

```
New
Open
Save
Save as
Copy
Paste
Cut
Select all
```

etc.

I'd like the user to be able to find commands by entering only a couple letters in succession. So if user entered, for instance, "ae", he should receive:

```
sAvE
sAvE as
pAstE
```

In general, when user enters "abc", I want to return all strings matching regular expression `.*a.*b.*c.*`. Since verifying whether string matchest this expression is linear and bruteforce algorithm is also linear, regular expressions won't help much in optimizing the search.

Important thing about this list is that it is known by compile-time, so I may design a data structure, which will hold all those terms to speed up the search.

Is there a data structure or an algorithm, which would speed up finding all matching words for specific user entry beyond O(m*n) (where m is count of terms and n - average term length)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, C#

Comment: Pure regex by itself can't really give you importance metric you want, but only a yes or no match.  You need something like the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, The yes-no match definitely suits my needs. I want to simplify search, such that user may enter only part of the term instead of the whole term. I don't want the algorithm to be sophisticated enough to correct mistakes as well (at least, yet)

Comment: How many commands do you have that a linear search isn't acceptable? Do you really need do optimize? Or do you just feel like it might be a good idea?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, now? 7 :) But this list will be growing and I plan to also add alternatives (eg. "Save = Write", maybe bad example, but you get it), quick access to settings, dialog windows etc. I suspect, that I'll have a couple of hundreds of commands.

Comment: Have you timed a linear search against say 500 strings and found it to be insufficiently responsive?

Comment: I implemented a similar search in my application based on a concept somewhat similar to the Levenshtein distance (and actually computationally more expensive than that) and match it versus thousands of strings and it works in real-time. so maybe dont worry too much

however, if you want to go for it, why not try to convert your strings into a bit vector for each letter, like ae -> 10001000... 
then you can check for matches with a simple binary AND
in a second step, you can check the order of the letters

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a case of premature optimization to me. Ridiculously premature. Even if you have 70 commands instead of just seven, the amount of time it will take to do a sequential search of all your commands is so small that your user won't notice it. And it's not like this is a function that you'll be calling hundreds or thousands of times per second. So spending hours implementing a fancy search to save a few milliseconds here and there is just wasted time. It's likely that the amount of time your users save over the life of the program won't even come close to the amount of time you'll spend designing, writing, and debugging your optimized solution.

You have a small number of very short commands. Computers are fast. There is no problem to solve here. Go spend your time on features that will actually benefit the user.

Now, if you had a very large number (tens of thousands) of strings to search, then you might benefit from some optimization. In that case . . .

You could start by making a dictionary that's keyed by letter, and the value is a list of all words that contain that letter. So your example would be something like:

```
a, [Save, Save as, Paste]
c, [Copy, Cut, Select all]
e, [New, Open, Save, Save as, Paste, Select all]
n, [New, Open]
... etc.
```

Then, make entries in the dictionary for "letter follows letter". This is going to get large in a hurry. "Paste," for example will have entries:

pa
  ps
  pt
  pe
  as
  at
  ae
  st
  se
  te

You can continue making those keys for longer substrings. For example, you get:

pas
  pat
  pae
  pst
  pse
  pte

This can be very effective when the strings are short. It becomes less effective when the strings get longer because the likelihood of a string containing a particular letter combination increases as the string length increases.

You could probably save some space by creating a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but the technique is essentially the same.

Also potentially useful: [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) and [generalized suffix tre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree)e.

Comment: tens of thousands of commands... I know where most of their development time should be spent then, and it's not on this search function :) That's a lot of commands to implement.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Tens of thousands of commands would be silly. But perhaps it's a search in a contact list that contains tens of thousands of names.

Comment: For sake of completeness, @JimMischel 's method takes, for k-letter sets, `O(m n^k)` memory and a similar time to preprocess, but the query takes `O(1)` time. It should be noted that for large k, this could easily end up using all available memory.

Comment: I believe a trie-like method would be something along the lines of a `List<Dictionary<char, int>>` for each word, where the inner dictionary stores pointers to the next Key letter (and the zeroth term simply the first occurrence of a given letter). This takes `O (m n^2)` memory and time to pre-process, but queries take `O(m t)`.

Comment: Given that the input is live, an efficient way of providing a quicker response is by having a 'current' set of commands, which is queried every time a new letter is added. (When combined with the previous method, that yields a solution in `O(m)` at every new letter added).

Answer (score 1):

As a wrote in my comment, probably you shouldn't worry about performance too much...

However, this data structure should fit your needs, let's call it a: Letter X before Y tree. Basically, a tree where each node has children for each letter if the letter appears after the parent nodes letter in the target word
For each node you would store a list of all the matches.

```
public class Node
{
    public char Letter { get; set; }

    public Node[] Children {get;set;}

    public List<string> CommandNames {get;set;} 
}
```

You can pre-fill it with all your known names like this

```
p paste
a paste
s paste
..
p/a paste
p/s paste
p/t paste
..
t/e paste
..
p/a/s paste
..
s/t/e paste
```

Matching your search word simply means traversing your tree for each letter entered by the user, so it boils down to O(n)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about its time complexity, yet if we just wish to search for words that must have `a` and `e` in it, we would be starting with an expression similar to the following, then we would optimize for runtime:

```
(?=.*a)(?=.*e).*
```

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?=.*a)(?=.*e).*";
        string input = @"New
Open
Save
Save as
Copy
Paste
Cut
Select all";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Byghzw/1/)